# Regex in Vim- inserting blank line before numbered lines

Tags: regex, vim

I have following text:

```
Title line
1. First list
First line
Second line
2. Second list
Oranges
Mangoes
3. Stationary
Pen
Pencils
Etc
```

I want to add a blank line before every numbered line, so that above text looks like following:

```
Title line

1. First list
First line
Second line

2. Second list
Oranges
Mangoes

3. Stationary
Pen
Pencils
Etc
```

I tried following code but it is not working:

```
%s/^(\d)/\r\1/g
```

and

```
%s/(^\d)/\r\1/g
```

and

%`s/^([0-9])/\r\1/gc`

Where is the problem and how can this be solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Escape parentheses in `%s/^(\d)/\r\1/g` => `%s/^\(\d\)/\r\1/g`

Comment: Another way: `%g/^\d/norm O`

Comment: Can you explain how it is working- it can be added as a separate answer.

Comment: I would try very magick option "\v": `%s/\v^(\d+)/\r\1/g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should escape parentheses within a VIM syntax in order to mean it a special cluster:

```
%s/^\(\d\)/\r\1/g
```

Or use an *end of match zero-width assertion* (`\ze`) token:

```
%s/^\ze\d/\r
```

Answer (score 3):

To use capture group `()` without having to escape them, use `\v` very magic (See `:h /magic`)

```
:%s/\v^(\d)/\r\1/
```

Note that `g` flag is redundant as there can be only one match at beginning of line

As entire matched string is needed in replacement section, one can simply use `&` or `\0` without needing explicit capture group

```
:%s/^\d/\r&/
```

Mentioned in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44909283/regex-in-vim-inserting-blank-line-before-numbered-lines#comment76797010_44909283)

```
:g/^\d/norm O
```

The `g` command allows filtering lines and executing command on those lines, like `norm O` to open new line above. Default range is entire file, so `%` is not needed

With substitute command, this would be `:g/^\d/s/^/\r/`

See `:h :g` and `:h ex-cmd-index` for complete list of commands to use with `:g`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the global command, `:g` to execute an empty `:put` on each line before the matching number, `^\d`.

```
:g/^\d/pu!_
```

Note: Using the blackhole register, `"_`, combined with `:put` to give us the empty line.

For more help see:

```
:h :g
:h /\d
:h :put
:h quote_
```